# Groovy - Filter ArrayList where identical array exists in another ArrayList

Tags: groovy

I am parsing two json files as follows:

```
def file1data = []
def file2data = []

sourceJson1.Records.each {recs ->

    String field1 = recs.cus_RBCounterpartyID_2wtne0
    String field2 = recs.AffectedParties[0].AffectedParties.SourceSystem

    file1data << [field1, field2]

}

sourceJson2.Records.each {recs2 ->

    String field1 = recs2.cus_RBCounterpartyID_2wtne0
    String field2 = recs2.AffectedParties[0].AffectedParties.SourceSystem

    file2data  << [field1, field2]

}
```

What I want to do now is remove entries in file1data where there is an identical entry in file2data.

Hope someone can suggest a suitable way of achieving this please.
Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Shouldn't `file1data.removeAll(file2data)` be enough? I'm pretty sure that should do it.